# the_tags only showing when logged in?

Tags: permissions, tags

I'm trying to figure out why the_tags(); when used in the loop are only showing when I'm logged in to the site.

I've never come across an issue like this before when developing themes.

my code is now on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/cSJy5kyH

As I said, the tags appear when logged in but only then. Am I missing a permission or some setting that has appeared in WordPress 3.2.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted work just fine , logged in or not .
I have confirmed it on my server in multiple locations.
There is something else in your theme that is causing it .
do you have any other conditional tags there ? like `is_admin()` `is_user_logged_in()` or any other  ??
Any plugin you installed while developing the theme ?

Comment: I'm using plugins I have before and none of the code I'm using that relies on `is_admin()` is causing tags to disappear.

There are also no plugins that effect the tags not showing.

Comment: well.. used before or not , for debugging, disable all of he plugins, and also all conditional tags. then enable one by one , and you will find your problem. also , one more thing to check .. does the tags appear in the CODE itself ? could it be a css problem ?

Comment: Not a CSS Problem or a Code problem that I can track down, have disabled all plugins and there is nothing on the front end that is conditional to stop tags showing.

Comment: can you post the whole code of the template file that makes the problem ? maybe on [http://pastebin.com]

Comment: Updated OP to include link

Comment: I really do not know what to say . putting your code in my theme does NOT reproduce your problem. tags are showing with no problem on all queries. This HAS to be plugin / function , or a defected wp installation.